# How to use localStorage in unit tests with Chai

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, chai

I have an app with react and redux. My test engine is - [Chai](http://chaijs.com/)

In my reducer (*src/my_reducer.js*), I try to get token from localStorage like this:

```
const initialState = {
  profile: {},
  token: window.localStorage.getItem('id_token') ? window.localStorage.getItem('id_token') : null,
}
```

In my tests file (*test/reducer_spec.js*) I have import 'my_reducer' before test cases:

```
import myReducer from '../src/my_reducer'
```

And I have an error, if I try to run test - localStorage (or window.localStorage) - undefined.

I need to mock localStorage? If I need, where is the place for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve problem with [mock-local-storage](https://github.com/letsrock-today/mock-local-storage)
My run test command is:

```
mocha -r mock-local-storage --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive
```

Comment: window.localStorage.getItem will return null if not found, so no need to check if it returns a value

Comment: @omerts, sry, I'm totally edit my answer to another... (I think it better, than post another one?)

Comment: @MaxP: potentially I'm misunderstanding something but I'm unable to access localStorage in my ReactJS tests until I attach your mock to the global context; i.e.,: `global.localStorage = window.localStorage;`.

Answer (score 7):

I presume you are running your tests with mocha?
mocha tests run in node.js, and node.js does not have a global window variable. But you can easily create one in your tests:

```
global.window = {};
```

You can even add the localStorage to it immediately:

```
global.window = { localStorage: /* your mock localStorage */ }
```

The mock depends on what you store in your local storage, but for the example code above this might be a reasonable mock object:

```
var mockLocalStorage = {
    getItem: function (key) {
        if( key === 'id_token' ){ return /* a token object */; }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Of course, for different tests you can have different mocks, e.g. another mock might always return `null` to test the case that the key cannot be found.

Comment: please can you provide a more complete example of localStorage object for tests?

Comment: @ArslArsl I have extended my answer and provided an example there. HTH :)

Comment: Getting this warning [ts] Cannot find name 'global'. Can you please help me here.

Comment: I have not tried this in TypeScript, but wouldn't it be sufficient just to define the variable? Like `const global = {};` or something?

Answer (score 2):

For testing purposes I recommend **not** to make any calls which may have side effects or call external modules in declarations.
Because requiring / importing your reducer implicitly calls `window.localStorage.getItem(...)` clean testing gets hard.

I'd suggest to wrap your initialization code with a `init` method so nothing happens if you require/import your module before calling `init`. Then you can use `beforeEach` `afterEach` to cleanly setup mocks/sandboxes.

```
import myReducer from '../src/my_reducer'
describe('with faked localStorage', function() {
  var sandbox

  beforeEach(function() {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()
    // fake window.localStorage
  })

  afterEach(function() {
    sandbox.restore()
  })

  describe('the reducer', function() {
    before(function() {
      myReducer.init()
    })
  })
})
```

The second best solution is to postpone the import and use `require` within the `before` test hook.

```
describe('with fake localStorage', function() {
  var sandbox

  beforeEach(function() {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()
    // fake window.localStorage
  })

  afterEach(function() {
    sandbox.restore()
  })

  describe('the reducer', function() {
    var myReducer

    before(function() {
      myReducer = require('../src/my_reducer')
    })

  })
})
```

Comment: try to implement this.. but, I don't use sinon

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not running Chai in a browser environment.

Try:

```
  // Make sure there is a window object available, and that it has localstorage (old browsers don't)
  const initialState = {
    profile: {},
    // window.localStorage.getItem('id_token') will return null if key not found
    token: window && window.localStorage ? window.localStorage.getItem('id_token') : null,
  }
```

Comment: Not helped: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: Are you sure it is from the above code? Since we are testing for the existence of window: token: window &&...

Comment: yeap, I'm sure. And surprised too.