# Is there a way to test whether or not something is added to localStorage?

Tags: javascript, express, testing, mocha.js, chai

I am currently testing a login function where the user_id of the logged in user should be added to localStorage.
However, i am unable to test this because of an uncaught reference error: "localStorage is not defined"
Could somebody help me figure this out? Have tried 'mocking' localStorage without succes.
Using mocha and chai for testing.

```
// Test if user_id is added to localstorage
it('should add user_id to localstorage', (done) => {
    chai.request(app)
        .post('/login')
        .send({
            username: 'admin',
            password: '1234'
        })
        .end((err, res) => {
            expect(localStorage.getItem('user_id')).to.equal('1');
            done();
        }
        );
}
);
```

Comment: If this is a test running in nodeJS there is no localstorage. That's solely available in the browser.

Comment: Understood, but i should be able to test it in nodeJS somehow though, right?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [testem](https://github.com/testem/testem) which [might help you out](https://knpw.rs/blog/testing-in-browsers-and-node).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304862/how-to-use-localstorage-in-unit-tests-with-chai